# VBA Excel WebBrowser how to reset ReadyState before .Click from the code?

Tags: excel, vba, webbrowser-control, reset, readystate

I have similar code in Excel VBA with WebBrowser control inserted in a form:

```
basePath = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/"
' Open main website (Home page)
WebBrowser.Navigate basePath

PauseTime = 30 ' Set duration to wait in seconds.
Start = Timer ' Set start time.
Do ' While Timer < Start + PauseTime
    DoEvents ' allow other processes to work (the browser to have time to load the webpage)
Loop Until WebBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or Timer > Start + PauseTime
```

This way I'm opening the specified URL.
Then I put bar-code value in the search field in the HTML and invoke .Click method on the "submit" button (HTML input element) for the same form.

I successfully open the search results page with what I'm searching for, but the browser control is already in WebBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE status and I cannot track when actually the browser control finished the second load - the search page in this case.

Is there a way to RESET the ReadyState property in order to know when the second load has finished?

Comment: Assuming you're just pasting text into the search field and not using any special search options, you could just navigate directly to the results by generating the search URL. eg:    `basePath = "http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/field-keywords=" & barcodeValue`

Answer (score 1):

Because `DocumentComplete` it not reliable (thank you Alex for the suggestion!) - sometimes it fires before the page is fully loaded resulting in missing part I need for my job, I ended using this:

```
Set MyObj = Nothing
Do
    DoEvents
    Set MyObj = WebBrowser.Document.all("myobjID")
Loop Until Not MyObj is Nothing
```

But it's temporary solution - i'm not sure i'll always have this myobjID in the DOM!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DocumentComplete` event which is raised when a document is fully loaded so should fire for every call to `.Navigate`.

(This includes frames so if any are present you will need to filter them using the URL argument the event receives)

Comment: Thanks Alex.
I used to try this event before, but it's not reliable - sometimes it fires before the page is fully loaded resulting in missing part I need for my job.

I ended using this:
Set MyObj = Nothing
Do
    DoEvents
    Set MyObj = WebBrowser.Document.all("myobjID")
Loop Until Not MyObj is Nothing

But it temporary solution - still waiting for the right one!